# VS hides error about a missing type in extension function call?

Tags: c#, generics, roslyn

we had to hunt down a really nasty problem in our code:

```
void Test()
{
    string queryString = @"...";
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(queryString, Connection);

    DataSet contacts = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(contacts, "employees");

    var contactList = new List<Contact>();
    foreach (DataRow item in contacts.Tables["employees"].Rows)
    {
        var foo = new Contact
        {
            Id = item.Field<int>("ID"),
            // ...
            LastChanged = item.Field<>("ID");
        };
    }

    return contactList;
}
```

See those empty angle brackets in line 16? Those were of course a mistake and should have been filled, since `System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>` is a generic extension method where the type is not inferrable.

For some reason Visual Studio (2015, Update 3) does not show an error in that line. However, when compiling, I'm greeted with this horribly useless error:

`CS7038: Failed to emit module '<assembly name here>'.`

...without any mention of the failing file or line. Filling in the type of course fixes this, but it seems more like a compiler error? I can reproduce this on two different computers/installations of VS.

Am I overlooking something or is this a bug I should report?

Comment: Why would that be a generic?

Comment: @Greg sorry, I didn't write that correctly, the type parameter itself does not have to be generic.

Comment: Repot the bug to the Roslyn site.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more testing it seems like a compiler bug when omitting the type information of a generic extension method. Reported issue and reproducable code can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16101).